# Failure to update DOM element content via Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

When using the JavaScript below, the element with id `#totalprice` doesn't update the second time.

```
$('.spinner_btn').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        spinner = $(this).siblings(".custom_spinner").data('spinnerclass');
        $('.'+spinner).addClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('hide');
        $('.orderbox').addClass("open");
       // $(this).siblings('.custom_spinner').children('.input-group').children('.input-number').val(1);
        $.ajax({
            'type' : "POST",
            'url'  : 'menus/temp',
            'data' : {
                '_token' : $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'menu_id' : $(this).siblings('.custom_spinner').children('.input-group').children('.menu_id').val(),
                'menu_name': $(this).siblings('.custom_spinner').children('.input-group').children('.menu_name').val(),
                'menu_price': $(this).siblings('.custom_spinner').children('.input-group').children('.menu_price').val(),
                'quantity' : $(this).siblings('.custom_spinner').children('.input-group').children('.input-number').val(),
            },
            success : function($data){
                alert($data.total);
                $('#totalprice').replaceWith($data.total);
                if($data.menus.edit == 'yes'){
                    if($data.quantity == 0){
                        $(".item" + $data.menus.id).replaceWith(
                            "<tr class='item" + $data.menus.id + "'><td>" + $data.menus.name + "</td><td>" +
                            $data.quantity + "</td><td>" + $data.quantity * $data.menus.price + "</td><td><span id='paddingcustom"
                             + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus cancelbox"+ "'"+"data-menuid='"+ $data.menus.id + "'></span>" +" </span>"
                            +"</td><td></td></tr>"
                        );
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#vouchertbl').append("<tr class='item" + $data.menus.id + "'><td>" + $data.menus.name + "</td><td>" +
                        $data.quantity + "</td><td>" + $data.quantity * $data.menus.price + "</td><td><span id='paddingcustom"
                        + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus cancelbox"+ "'"+"data-menuid='"+ $data.menus.id + "'></span>" +" </span>"
                        +"</td><td></td></tr>"
                    );
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Alert on data.total show the correct output but update failed on id.I have read some about delegate but I am new to jquery and don't know the syntax for simple element .

Comment: Please tell us what you have read about "delegate", how it it relevant and where you read it. We like to see what research you've done, and what you've tried to do to solve the issue, in advance of offering answers; it saves time.

Comment: I just read about .on() method that update the future element like . https://jsfiddle.net/3nL3cu7q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are replacing the `#totalprice` element, since is not working in the second time 
Instead of

```
$('#totalprice').replaceWith($data.total);
```

**try**

```
$('#totalprice').text($data.total);
```

Refer these [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) & [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)